# Ruby gsub! with Regex keep word

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to turn a string line `"variable.to_s"` into `"str(variable)"` using `gsub!` with regex. I currently have

```
string = "variable.to_s"
string.gsub!(/\w+\.to_s/,/str(\w)/)
```

which obviously does not work as you cannot use regex in the second part of gsub, but how do I keep the `\w` found in the gsub part but replacing the `.to_s` part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're capturing the wrong thing:

```
string.gsub!(/(\w+)\.to_s/, 'str(\1)')
```

`gsub` and `gsub!` take a string or regular expression as the first argument and a string or block as the second argument. You're sending a regular expression to both.

If you need to use a portion of the match in the second part, capture it with brackets. You did this inadvertently in your code but on the wrong side.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! I'll accept your answer once it permits me to!